# Material UI Web App packaged with Cordova as IOS APP

Tags: ios, reactjs, cordova, material-ui

We have created a Web App using material UI and React JS. It is working great and wanted to bundle it as a mobile app using Cordova.

The bundled Cordova Android app has been accepted on Google Play. However, the IOS version has been rejected by App store review team.

Reason given: 
4.2 - Design

We continue to find your app provides a limited user experience as it is not sufficiently different from a mobile browsing experience. As such, the experience it provides is similar to the general experience of using Safari. It would be appropriate to include additional iOS interactive features within your app before resubmitting for review.

Has anyone managed to publish a react web app as an IOS app. What advice would you give us?